# Remove quotation mark from <th> tag in View Model

Tags: html, viewmodel

This is my case:

`<th class="myClass" title="hello" world>myText</th>`

And I want it to become:

`<th class="myClass" title="hello world">myText</th>`

This is how i populated the title:

`@{string myTitle = Model.MyTitle;}`

`<th class="myClass" title=@myTitle>myText</th>`

Model.MyTitle = "hello world".

As I see, it separates multiple words into multiple attributes. Why? :

`<th class="myClass" title="hello" world="">myText</th>`

I used title attribute for Powertip.

Comment: you need to make sure that the title attribute is already correctly filled. Why is `world` not inside `title` on page generation?

Comment: that's why I am asking too.

This is how i populated it:
@{string myTitle= Model.MyTitle;}
<th colspan="1" class="myClass" title=@myTitle>myText</th>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem doing this: 

 `<th class="myClass" title="@myTitle">myText</th>`